# Flutter: path.join is not joining strings

Tags: flutter, join, path

I am using the join function from the package path.dart to build a file path.  However it doesn't seem to be joining the strings, and just returns the last one.

For example:

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

String _docsDir = (await getApplicationDocumentDirectory()).path;
String xmlRelativePath = '/xmlfiles/myfile.xml';
String xmlFullPath = '';

xmlFullPath = path.join(,_docsDir, xmlRelativePath );           // outputs: /xmlfiles/myfile.xml

xmlFullPath = path.join('ARRRRGGG',_docsDir, xmlRelativePath ); // outputs: /xmlfiles/myfile.xml
```

but if I just paste them together in a string it works fine:

```
xmlFullPath = '$_docsDir$xmlRelativePath'
```

Really scratching my head here.  Is there something obvious I am missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`path.join` does not just concatenate strings.  Your last argument starts with a path separator and is treated as an *absolute* path (despite your desire to treat it as a relative path), so it will override all the previous arguments.  This is explained in the [`path.join` documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/path/latest/path/join.html):

> If a part is an absolute path, then anything before that will be ignored:
>
> ```dart
> p.join('path', '/to', 'foo'); // -> '/to/foo'
> ```

Either change `xmlRelativePath` to *not* start with a directory separator or, instead of using `path.join`, use a normal string concatenation followed by [`path.normalize`](https://pub.dev/documentation/path/latest/path/normalize.html):

```dart
xmlFullPath = path.normalize(['ARRRRGGG', docsDir, xmlRelativePath].join('/'));
```

(Because you're using XML paths, I'm using `'/'` directly as the directory separator.)

Comment: Thank you!  I read the documentation several times and I must have missed that that third bit  about absolute path every time.  This is indeed what is happening.  Also thank you for the normalization recommendation.